declared program id mismatch
We copied a solana program from a youtube vid. The program id : Ecr5UgGyJTnKraLRPYBXrK9RD7DfoVDYfSioVksnnfjA is this one. We copied it and deployed it on our own and here is what we got. program id : 6bhh8wkUfx8e19KJnkHmysWw2Aq1zMAUHJ47gRsK5t1e. We then tried to call it's function with the code below:
export async function updateMessage(
  inputtedMessage: string,
  wallet: AnchorWallet,
  messageAccount: web3.Keypair // this is the account that will store messages
) {
  const provider = new AnchorProvider(connection, wallet, { preflightCommitment: commitmentLevel });

  if (!provider) return;

  /* create the program interface combining the idl, program Id, and provider */
  const program = new Program(
    HELLO_WORLD_PROGRAM_INTERFACE,
    HELLO_WORLD_PROGRAM_ID,
    provider
  ) as Program<SolanaHelloWorld>;

  try {
    // This one is saying that rpc is deprecated
    // const txn = await program.rpc.updateMessage(inputtedMessage, {
    //   accounts: {
    // message: messageAccount.publicKey,
    // author: provider.wallet.publicKey,
    // systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId,
    //   }, 
    // });
    const txn = await program.methods
      .updateMessage(inputtedMessage)
      .accounts({
        message: messageAccount.publicKey,
        author: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: web3.SystemProgram.programId
      })
      .rpc();
    return txn;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("updateMessage error ", error);
    return;
  }

}

This is working for the code of the youtube vid code but for the one we copied it gives an error :
    at AnchorError.parse (index.js:1203:1)
    at translateError (index.js:1305:1)
    at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (index.js:4946:1)
    at async updateMessage (VM387 createMessage.ts:58:21)
    at async callUpdateMessage (index.tsx:61:20)```


This is a bit of a shot in the dark without knowing more info, but I think you'll need to update your program id to match the deployed program id so that you call the right program.
This likely means changing HELLO_WORLD_PROGRAM_ID to new PublicKey('6bhh8wkUfx8e19KJnkHmysWw2Aq1zMAUHJ47gRsK5t1e').

i did but it is not working still i think i have set everything to deploy this contract on devnet still it is not deploying my contrac on devnet it is still deploying it either on localnet or testnet .  as i was getting same error in my previous contract i set devnet in config file that work their . but not working in my current contract ..

Error  Error: Account does not exist or has no data Dj5xiazocuWZ53Fpe4wj7jy4yhVaLWEs96697haf8QhC
my read function is working means that getting above error means my program id  is correct
